# How to read data on Android phone sent from Bluetooth UART device connected to microcontroller?

Tags: android, arduino

I have an Arduino microcontroller that I will be using [this Bluetooth module with](http://www.sureelectronics.net/goods.php?id=402). My eventual goal is get the Arduino to be able to speak to my Android phone over Bluetooth. By speak I mean send it data and receive data.

The hardware of this I understand. I will be able to hook this Bluetooth module up and make it a function as I want. The only part I would not know how to do is read the data in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An awesome toolkit that you should checkout is the [Amarino Toolkit](http://www.amarino-toolkit.net)! It was designed specifically for Arduino and Android communication. You can you send data and event triggers from your Android phone to the Arduino. You can also send data from real time sensors connected to the arduino to you phone.

Take a look at SensorGraph [example](http://code.google.com/p/amarino/downloads/detail?name=SensorGraph.zip&can=2&q=) on their main website. It shows you how to do everything from connecting to the Bluetooth UART module to actually sending data to your phone. Also [here](http://bygriz.com/blog/) is a nifty walkthrough related to that same example problem.
Cheers'

Comment: @ptk does that work also for other MCUs than Arduino?